# how to compare records to a table, and insert into an existing temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table that I created:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempIDS (
Name varchar(108),
Id uniqueidentifier,
IsUser bit )
```

and I've populated it:

```
INSERT INTO #tempIDS (Name, Id)
SELECT UName, UId FROM UList
WHERE UName LIKE 'smi%'
ORDER BY UName
```

so now what I want to do is check the records in the temp table against another table to see if they exist. If they're in the other table, then I want to put a "1", if not, a "0".

And therein lies my problem.

If I do this:
select count(A.UId) 
from Staff A, #tempIDS B
where A.UId = '480FA1E3-1A4B-4D3B-AB21-5070ADF974EB'

I can get a "1" or a "0".

But how do I do select and insert either a "1" or "0" into my temp table based on if the record exists in the comparing table? 
This won't work:

```
update #tempIDS
set IsUser = (select COUNT(StaffId) FROM Staff
where StaffId= (select Id from #tempIDS))
```

help?

Answer (score 2):

```
 UPDATE #tempIDS
 SET IsUser= CASE WHEN COALESCE(staff.staffid,0) = 0  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
 FROM #tempIDS
 LEFT OUTER JOIN staff ON #tempIDS.id = staff.staffid
```

Sorry it looks like you want to update IsUser I was updating ID

Comment: Thanks Conrad!

I get the following error when I enter this though: 
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Can you please tell me what this means?


I also tried:
update #tempIDS
SET IsUser = CASE WHEN COALESCE(Count(UList.StaffId), 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM #tempIDS
LEFT OUTER JOIN UList on #tempIDS.Id = UList.StaffId

but get this:
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Giselle W I changed ID to IsUser on the set statement

Answer (score 0):

You could default the IsUser column to 0 and then you would only have to update rows where you found matching staff ids.